# Why do my IIS site-specific application settings disappear?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, app-config, webdeploy

I'm hosting an ASP.NET C# website using IIS on Windows Server. I publish to the IIS server using Web Deploy. I have a few application settings that I configure via IIS' site-specific application settings - mostly passwords that I don't want in plain-text in my app.config within the project itself. Every time that I publish, the settings that I've created via IIS disappear. I think the publish is over writing them. I can't figure out how to get them to persist through publishes. Does anybody know how to get the IIS application settings to remain even through Web Deploy publishes?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think this happens because when you make those changes in IIS, it persists them by just editing your web.config and adding them. So when you redeploy, a new web.config gets copied over, and overwrites your settings. How to prevent this, I'm not sure...

Comment: Unless you can apply identical changes to your development web.config file the settings will continue to be overwritten. Changes you made in an IIS app that is not mapped to your development build output folder will not persist during web deploys. I avoid auto deploying web config files from machine to machine as it can lead to issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that solves your problem, but you could try something like this:

Every config section has an optional attribute named "configSource" to
point to an external file. Therefore you could break down your web.config
into several files and update them accoringly:

web.config:

```
...
<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config"/>
    <system.web>
...
```

connectionStrings.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="defaultConnectionString" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then you could set the connectionString.config to not be included in the output of the project and just keep it unchanged on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could also:
-create a new build configuration for deployment
-add a web.config transformation for this build configuration
-deploy using this build configuration
That's how I usually do it